# Create a new column based on calculations that change between rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to calculate a sum of variables for a given day. Each day contains a different calculation, but all the days use the variables consistently.

There is a df which specifies my variables and a df which specifies how calculations will change depending on the day.

How can I create a new column containing answers from these different equations?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

conversion = [["a",5],["b",1],["c",10]]
conversion_table = pd.DataFrame(conversion,columns=['Variable','Cost'])

data1 = [[1,"3a+b"],[2,"c"],[3,"2c"]]
to_solve = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Day','Q1'])

desired = [[1,16],[2,10],[3,20]]
desired_table=pd.DataFrame(desired,columns=['Day','Q1 solved'])
```

I have separated my variables and equations based on row. Can I loop though these equations to find non-numerics and re-assign them?

```
#separate out equations and values 

for var in conversion_table["Variable"]:
    cost=(conversion_table.loc[conversion_table['Variable'] == var, 'Cost']).mean()

for row in to_solve["Q1"]:
    equation=row
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you show your expected output dataframe

Comment: the output dataframe is: desired_table

Comment: oh ok, Is it possible for `3a` to be rewritten as `3*a` so eval can be used?

Comment: yes, the equations can be rewritten

Comment: ok i submitted a possible solution, please verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple suggestion, perhaps you need to rewrite a part of your code. Not sure if your want something like this:

```
a = 5
b = 1
c = 10

# Rewrite the equation that is readable by Python
# e.g. replace 3a+b by 3*a+b
data1 = [[1,"3*a+b"],
         [2,"c"],
         [3,"2*c"]]

desired_table = pd.DataFrame(data1,
                        columns=['Day','Q1'])
desired_table['Q1 solved'] = desired_table['Q1'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
desired_table
```

Output:

```
   Day     Q1  Q1 solved
0    1  3*a+b         16
1    2      c         10
2    3    2*c         20
```

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for showing me the eval(x) part! Yes its possible for me to re-write those equations in the data1 df, but I  would like to know how to remove the cost variables from their dataframe. (I will be doing this over many files and cannot individually assign the variables) For the last line to work though, I think the last line should be: desired_table['Q1 solved'] = to_solve['Q1'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to have the equations changed to equations with `*` then you could do this.

Get the mapping from the

`mapping = dict(zip(conversion_table['Variable'], conversion_table['Cost'])`

the eval the function and replace variables with numeric from the mapping

```
desired_table['Q1 solved'] = to_solve['Q1'].map(lambda x: eval(''.join([str(mapping[i]) if i.isalpha() else str(i) for i in x])))
```

```
0    16
1    10
2    20
```

Comment: This works on the example-- thank you! Could you clarify, in my actual data table, I get the following error: 'float' object is not iterable. Can this code still work there?

Comment: The issue arises when there are NaN values in some of the rows-- is there a way to use this code and skipping over those values?

Comment: i would filter out those NaN rows before runing that code, `df[df['Q1'].notnull()]`

Comment: @user11548079 have you found an acceptable answer so this question can be closed