# Apply a lambda function to a dataframe with NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to perform calculations that change between rows with variables that remain consistent. How can I use this lambda function when a row has incomplete data?

Follow up to this question: [Create a new column based on calculations that change between rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61882878/create-a-new-column-based-on-calculations-that-change-between-rows)

```
#example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

conversion = [["a",5],["b",1],["c",10]]
conversion_table = pd.DataFrame(conversion,columns=['Variable','Cost'])

data1 = [[1,"2*a+b"],[2,"c"],[3,"2*c"],[4, np.NaN]]
to_solve = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Day','Q1'])

#Desired dataframe: 

desired = [[1,11],[2,10],[3,20]]
desired_table=pd.DataFrame(desired,columns=['Day','desired output'])

#Using lambda to map values does not work when NaN is present.

#Map values
mapping = dict(zip(conversion_table['Variable'], conversion_table['Cost']))

desired_table["solved"]=to_solve['Q1'].map(lambda x: eval(''.join([str(mapping[i]) if i.isalpha() else str(i) for i in x])))
```

This code works when my columns do not contain NaN values, but I need this to work when I have incomplete data.
I receive the following error: 'float' object is not iterable. 
I just want to leave the NaN values where they are and fill in the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add an optional parameter `na_action='ignore'` to the `.map` method which *propagate NaN values, without passing them to the mapping correspondence*

Use:

```
def solve(x):
    expr = ''.join(str(mapping[k]) if k in mapping else str(k) for k in x)
    return pd.eval(expr)

desired_table["solved"]= to_solve['Q1'].map(solve, na_action='ignore')
```

This results the `desired_table` as:

```
   Day  desired output  solved
0    1              11    11.0
1    2              10    10.0
2    3              20    20.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for re-writing it slightly. Helped so much when I went on to using this in other functions accros many columns!

Answer (score 5):

```
desired_table["solved"]=to_solve['Q1'].map(lambda x: ..., na_action='ignore')
```

should do what you want.

```
In [6]: to_solve['Q1'].map(lambda x: eval(''.join([str(mapping[i]) if i.isalpha() else str(i) for i in x])), na_action='ignore')                                                                            
Out[6]: 
0    11.0
1    10.0
2    20.0
3     NaN
Name: Q1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter out NaN values:

```
desired_table["solved"]=to_solve.loc[~to_solve['Q1'].isna(),'Q1'].map(
      lambda x: eval(''.join([str(mapping[i]) if i.isalpha() else str(i) for i in x])))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `np.NaN` is of type `float`, so when you try to iterate over it (as you would when using strings) you get that SyntaxError. In order to avoid it, just make another condition in the lambda function for defining a default value when you have a `np.NaN` in your data.

```
def mappingFunc(x):
    return eval(''.join([str(mapping[i]) if i.isalpha() else str(i) for i in x])) if x is not np.NaN else np.NaN

desired_table["solved"] = to_solve['Q1'].map(mappingFunc)
```